# User saw Inspect Element Changes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was using Dev Tools Inspect element in Chrome to show my team a preview of what our website would look like if we changed a few things.

We are using Hotjar to get Feedback and we see that a user sent feedback with a screenshot of our website. In the screenshot I can see the changes we were playing with in Dev Tools. I am wondering how this is possible...

Comment: There is an extension that allows sharing devtools customizations. I don't remember the name tho.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be both ways though? I don't have any kind of sharing extension installed...

Comment: You must have set up your source folder in [devtools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/).

Comment: Even with workspaces, doesn't it save to a local source file? I don't believe I have workspaces set up anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make in google chrome devtools are locally, so they can't be seen by other users